# Setting default value to dropdown of antdesign

Tags: reactjs, antd

I am using dropdown of ant design but I am not able to active one value from the dropdown list. How to give default value?

```
      <Dropdown
        value="1st menu item"
        trigger={["click"]}
        className={css`
          background-color: #0a3150;
          height: 65px;
          display: flex;
          justify-content: space-between;
          padding: 0px 28px;
          font-size: 17px;
          color: white;
          align-items: center;
          cursor: pointer;
        `}
        overlay={this.renderList()}
      >
        <div>
            CLick me <Icon type="down" />
        </div>
      </Dropdown>
```

it do not take the value that is assigned.

In renderList()

```
   <Menu>
      <Menu.Item>1st menu item</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item>2nd menu item</Menu.Item>
     <SubMenu title="sub menu">
      <Menu.Item>3rd menu item</Menu.Item>
      <Menu.Item>4th menu item</Menu.Item>
     </SubMenu>
     <SubMenu title="disabled sub menu" disabled>
       <Menu.Item>5d menu item</Menu.Item>
       <Menu.Item>6th menu item</Menu.Item>
     </SubMenu>
   </Menu>
```

//that value is in the list

Comment: For selecting a one value. You need to use antD select component. Dropdown is only  for action. You can't set default value.(you can only by managing val)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As it was pointed out, usually you will rather go for the `Select` component of antD in order to have a default value option. (https://ant.design/components/select)

Nevertheless, it is possible to achieve what you want with the `Dropdown` component. You just need to make sure that you are saving the current selected value after you clicked on the item and render it instead of a static value:

```
import React from "react";
import ReactDOM from "react-dom";
import "antd/dist/antd.css";
import "./index.css";
import { Menu, Dropdown, Icon } from "antd";

const menuItems = [
  {
    key: 1,
    value: "1st menu item"
  },
  {
    key: 2,
    value: "2nd menu item"
  },
  {
    key: 3,
    value: "3rd menu item"
  }
];

const CustomDropdown = () => {
  const [selected, setSelected] = React.useState("Select value");

  const handleMenuClick = e => {
    console.log(e.key);
    const newSelected = menuItems.find(item => item.key === parseInt(e.key, 10))
      .value;
    setSelected(newSelected);
  };

  const menu = (
    <Menu onClick={handleMenuClick}>
      {menuItems.map(item => (
        <Menu.Item key={item.key}>{item.value}</Menu.Item>
      ))}
    </Menu>
  );

  return (
    <Dropdown overlay={menu} trigger={["click"]}>
      <a className="ant-dropdown-link" href="#">
        {selected} <Icon type="down" />
      </a>
    </Dropdown>
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<CustomDropdown />, document.getElementById("container"));
```

Please see it working here: 
https://codesandbox.io/s/loving-beaver-nxbys

Comment: Hey Thanks for great example :)